How can I make this Python Polars code more efficient for calculating Indicators
I have an IndicatorManager class in Python that takes a Polars DataFrame and calculates 60 indicators, some using TA-Lib and others implemented with Polars code. I've noticed that when I run the class with a limit of 210, the values differ between historical data and the limited data.
To address this, I'm trying to calculate the data using windows of 210 rows and retrieve the last row for the entire DataFrame. However, I haven't been able to find an efficient Polars solution for this.
The data  is Cryptocurrency data that is fetched from Binance API with python-binance  library and stored as a csv file.
For example, a 5 minute data from BTCUSDT



date
open
high
low
close
volume




2021-12-28 16:05:00
49100.29
49140.9
48974.24
49140.9
160.13001


2021-12-28 16:10:00
49140.9
49187.2
49052.37
49079.09
121.37887


2021-12-28 16:15:00
49079.09
49129.0
49056.42
49110.6
86.7198



This is a 3 row data. I currently have 751.583 rows of data in 5 minute BTCUSDT
How can I optimize the run function in the IndicatorManager class to make it faster and more efficient?
Below is the current run function:
def run(self, data: pl.DataFrame) -> pl.DataFrame:
    return pl.concat(
        [
            self._calculate(data.slice(i, 210)).tail(-1)
            for i in range(len(data) - 209)
        ]
    )

And the _calculate method is just calculating indicators one by one.
def _calculate(self, data: pl.DataFrame) -> pl.DataFrame:
    indicators = [
        self._ao, self._cci, self._cfo, self._macd, self._rsi, self._tsi, self._uo, self._willr,
        *[lambda d: self._ema(d, p) for p in (10, 20, 50, 100, 200)],
        *[lambda d: self._sma(d, p) for p in (10, 20, 50, 100, 200)], self._supertrend,
        *[lambda d: self._wma(d, p) for p in (10, 20, 50, 100, 200)],
        self._adx, self._aroon, self._bbands, self._cmf, self._mfi, self._obv, self._kama, 
        self._ppo, self._pvo, self._roc, self._stochrsi, self._stoch, self._ad, self._eom, 
        self._efi, self._nvi, self._pvt, self._vwap, self._donchian, self._kc, self._ui, 
        self._ichimoku, self._kst, self._massi, self._psar, self._stc, self._trix, self._vortex, 
        self._cmo, self._wvf, self._crsi, self._dmi, self._ttm, self._vwmacd, self._ci,
        self._ft, self._atr
    ]

    for indicator in indicators:
        data = indicator(data)

    return data

I didn't give the whole IndicatorManager class because I didn't want to get too complicated due to IndicatorManager's 1000 lines of code
For example the _ao function is:
def _ao(self, data: pl.DataFrame) -> pl.DataFrame:
    fast = 5
    slow = 34

    median_price = 0.5 * (data["high"] + data["low"])
    return data.with_columns(
        (self.__sma(median_price, fast) - self.__sma(median_price, slow)).alias(f"AO_{fast}_{slow}")
    )

and the __sma function is:
@staticmethod
def __sma(
        close: pl.Series,
        length: int
) -> pl.Series:
    return talib.SMA(close, length)

I also tried using this alternative function, but the LazyDataFrame's group_by does not have an apply function:
def run(self, data: pl.DataFrame) -> pl.DataFrame:
    window_size = 210
    
    data = data.with_row_index()
    
    result = (
        data
        .lazy()
        .filter(pl.col("index") >= window_size - 1)
        .with_columns(
            (pl.col("index") - (window_size - 1)).alias("window_start")
        )
        .group_by("window_start", maintain_order=True)
        .apply(lambda df: self._calculate(
            data.slice(int(df["window_start"][0]), window_size)
        ).tail(1))
    ).collect()

    return result


It is basically impossible to answer this without a runnable example. apply was renamed to map_groups but it runs an external UDF in Python so will kill performance. It seems the general issue is you want to create groups of N rows and put your logic inside .agg? e.g. lf.with_row_index().with_columns((pl.col.index % 210 == 0).cum_sum()).group_by("index").agg(..) 

@jqurious Yes, it is basically it. I don't have a code that is compitable with 'LazyFrame' at the moment, but will try your suggestion after I get it to work with 'LazyFrame'. I'm considering to publish the code to an open github repository, then it will be possible to ask the readers for their more detailed help. Thank you for your comment.
